How to resolve the conflicts locally the same way as resolving the conflicts on github?
Let's say I have a branch called feature-branch, and it's behind main by several commits. When I try to merge main into my feature-branch locally using:
git merge origin/main
Git pulls in all the changes from main, including both the conflicting and non-conflicting files. This results in a lot of file changes in my branch, even if I only care about resolving conflicts.
For example, if main has changes in 100 files, but I only have conflicts in 5 of them, a normal git merge origin/main would show all 100 files as changed in my branch. This makes my pull request (PR) look like I changed 100 files (even though I didn’t), which makes it much harder to review.
Here’s what happens in this case:
I run git merge origin/main.
Git attempts to merge all the files from main into my feature-branch, and I see a lot of changes in my staging area (both conflicting and non-conflicting files).
As a result, my PR shows a large number of file changes, even the ones I didn’t touch.
What I want to do is only resolve the conflicting files, without pulling in all the non-conflicting changes from main. This is similar to how GitHub’s conflict resolution works — GitHub only shows me the conflicting files and allows me to resolve just those. Non-conflicting files are not included in the PR.
Example of What I Want:
Imagine main has changes in these files:
file1.js (no conflict)
file2.js (no conflict)
file3.js (conflict)
file4.js (conflict)

In GitHub’s conflict resolution interface:

I only see file3.js and file4.js (the conflicting files).
I can resolve the conflicts in those files without pulling in the changes from file1.js and file2.js.
As a result, my pull request shows only the files I needed to resolve (i.e., file3.js and file4.js).
But when I do this locally using git merge, I get changes from all the files (file1.js, file2.js, file3.js, and file4.js), and my PR ends up with a lot of unnecessary file changes.

What I Want to Know:
I’m asking if there’s a way to only resolve the conflicts locally — just like GitHub does — without pulling in all the non-conflicting changes from main. I want my PR to only show changes to the files that had conflicts, not all the files that were updated in main.

@ryanwebjackson I have edited my question and included examples to make it clearer.

I don't know what the Github merge interface does exactly. But I assume that it merges the feature branch into main, but locally you merge main into the feature branch. The resulting project states are absolutely identical if done correctly, regardless of the merge direction. At Github the set of changes looks far smaller, because it only takes your changes, whereas locally your see everything that happened on main. I wouldn't mind. (But then, I wouldn't merge main into the feature branch in the first place.)

@ryanwebjackson who says that is a best practice? It’s a practice.

There is a false premise in your question, "This makes my pull request (PR) look like I changed 100 files (even though I didn’t), which makes it much harder to review." This should not be the case. (Did you actually witness it or are you just assuming that would happen?) Those 100 files should not show up in the PR if your target branch is main. After resolving the conflicts for the 5 files, and pushing your branch again, only files you changed should be shown in the PR. If those 100 files are showing up, then something else is going on that you aren't telling us.

@TTT As I understand it, the 100 files are showing up locally when the remote main branch is merged with git pull. It makes total sense to me.

@j6t I assume we're saying the same thing? The 100 files should show up as local changes when you're in the middle of the merge. But OP is claiming that after resolving conflicts, completing the merge, and then pushing the branch, that the PR is also showing those 100 changes. I don't believe that should be the case since those changes are in commits already reachable by main.

@j6t My guess is OP didn't actually continue with updating the local branch and pushing out the changes, and if they do that, they will realize the PR is perfectly fine and they can probably delete this question.

One way to avoid your pull request (PR) from showing changes other than your own is to locally merge the latest from the target branch ("main" in this case) into your feature branch. Assuming you are currently on your feature branch, you can use the following strategy:

git commit (if any changes outstanding on your branch)
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout [your-feature-branch-name] (omit the square brackets when typing your actual branch name)
git merge main
git mergetool (or your other favorite method of resolving merge conflicts, assuming there are some at this step)
git merge --continue
git push (append origin/[your-feature-branch-name] if necessary)

At this point, if you have a pull request created, GitHub will show only your feature branch changes, with no merge conflicts. It is a good idea to check with any team members to see if anyone is merging to "main" at the same time, so that you don't have to perform this process multiple times for the same branch in rapid succession.

I want my PR to only show changes to the files that had conflicts, not all the files that were updated in main

I am reading in between the lines, but the type of issue you are describing can happen when commits are squashed on the target branch, and your feature branch is out of date. Essentially, commits on your feature branch that aren't yours are making it appear to git that there are some changes that need to be merged (when it is possible that those files are the same, or are subsequently changed in the target branch).
It's also worth noting that a different way to ensure that your branch is up-to-date is to simply create a new branch from the latest "main", and cherry-pick the commits from your existing feature branch. This will ensure that you have the latest from "main" — it's another strategy you can use.

It is the step 5 git merge main that shows 100 modified files plus a few conflicts by which OP is confused. But it is totally normal.
